# Assigning default argument values

Tags: python

Using this script:

```
color = 'blue'

def say_color(color):
    print 'The color is: ' + color

say_color()
```

Here, I am trying to allow `say_color` to be processed without passing an argument, and the result being the default color (blue). However, if a color is specified, it will not use blue and use the string given instead.

How is this done?

Answer (score 9):

```
def say_color(color='blue'):
    print 'The color is: ' + color

say_color()
```

Answer (score 6):

```
default_color = 'blue'

def say_color(color=default_color):
    print 'The color is: ' + color
```

then:

```
say_color()  # default_color is used
say_color('red')
```

yields:

```
The color is: blue
The color is: red
```

If you *don't* specify a `color` in your call, the `default_color` will be used in your `say_color` function. If you *do* specify a `color` in the call, then it will override your default value.

*Addendum*: For a more technical explanation/background about how and when these values are assigned/bound, please see the informative comment by @HughBothwell (thanks!) below.

Comment: Writing it this way can be misleading. `color` gets bound to the value of `default_color` *at the time say_color is defined*. Setting default_color to a different value later will not change the function's default color... *unless* default_color refers to a mutable object (list, dict, class, etc) in which case changes to the object's contents **can** propagate into the function, which can be unexpected and confusing.

Comment: @user1417933  Just a friendly note, if any one of these answers provided solved your problem please consider accepting one - thanks.